# Cassandra static columns

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and What I am trying to accomplish is that I have resources table which is a part of an e-learning platform that I am designing .. so that table have the courseId as its partition key and the sectionId as a clustering key then the resourceId as another clustering key then the rest of the data .. so now I want to add the section_name column into the table in a way that its value isn't copied into every resource under the sectionId and I think the way to do it probably similar to the static column but instead of being static for each partition key(courseId in our case) it should be static just for the (sectionId) .. so my question is there is a feature that can do that or there's any way to achieve this. One way that comes to my mind now is to make a table for the course sections and another table for the resources that has the sectionId as its partition key and that way we can make the section_name a static column. Another solution is to keep the table as it's and just create another one that have the courseId as a partition key and the sectionId as a clustering key then I put the section_name under that primary key. The problem why I don't want to make the section_name to be copied into every resource as if there's an update in the section name ( which I think is not likely to happen alot) it will require me to update all the resources in the section.
Side Note : I am using microservices so the resources table is my boundaries. And Sorry fot the title if it wasn't expressive enough

Comment: Make question readable. punctuation is not good, you could have added table definition in question.

Comment: Not my native language and I find its punctuation a little bit confusing and I don't have a table definition yet to add.. but I will look at what I can do for the readability part. but looking at your answer I think you got the question pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. All rows of a partition share the same value in the static column.

This isn't the right way to model data in Cassandra:

> One way that comes to my mind now is to make a table for the course sections and another table for the resources that has the sectionId as its partition key ...

Data is denormalised in Cassandra so you don't do joins or foreign lookups.

For each app query, you need to design a table with all the data required to respond to that app query. Cheers!

Comment: Thank You. I get you and that's what I am trying to accomplish to have one table for my query but the problem here that I will store the section_name for each resource .. what I am trying to accomplish is to have one table for the query to avoid joining tables and store the section name once for each section to avoid updating the same data in multiple rows .. so do you have any suggestions about the proper way of doing that if it exists of course or do you think it's not a problem for Cassandra to store the data multiple times (sometimes hundred time)

Comment: It isn't a problem to store data multiple times in Cassandra. You do it so reads are faster at the cost of multiple writes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think, looking at your question, the below table design should solve your problem -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resource_by_courseId _sectionId 
(
 courseId  text,
 sectionId  text,
 resourceId  text,
 section_name text static
 primary key ((courseId,sectionId),resourceId)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (resourceId DESC);
```

section_name is static, this will remain constant for (courseId,sectionId).

Comment: Well sadly this is ain't gonna work for me as I need to be able to access the table with just the courseId.